# is there a way to take text from input type file and proccess the text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to preview a text from a text file through input type file using javascript
i tried using the file directly in my code but error is prompted saying file is undefiend
but when i use file.value or print file to console an object from file is displayed

```js
function readInsideFile()
{
         const [file] = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;
         console.log(file);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        
    // this will then display a text file
        var text = reader.readAsText(file);
        console.log(text);
         var firstLine = text.split('\n').shift(); // first line 
        
         var sensorsoutputfield = document.getElementById("Rectangle_8_bu");
         sensorsoutputfield.innerHTML = firstLine;
    
    
}
```

Comment: Clear example in the docs: [FileReader.readAsText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText)

Comment: i used the readAsText and it returned undefined but when i log the reader object var text = reader.readAsText(file);
  console.log(reader); i find the result set to a value

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader *The FileReader object lets web applications **asynchronously** read the contents of files*...

Comment: https://simon-schraeder.de/posts/filereader-async/

Comment: tried but not giving any output reader.onload = () => {
    console.log(reader.result);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read files, but you must write lambda functions for reader. Use this
[Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-a-local-text-file-using-javascript/)

```
function readInsideFile()
{
     const files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;
     console.log(files);
     const reader = new FileReader();
     // this will then display a text file
     reader.onload = () => {
         var content = reader.result;
         console.log(text);
         var firstLine = text.split('\n').shift(); // first line
         var sensorsoutputfield = 
         document.getElementById("Rectangle_8_bu");
         sensorsoutputfield.innerHTML = firstLine;
     }
     reader.readAsText(this.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: i've used the readAsText function as you can see in my code snippt

Comment: No. You need use listener of input file to handle new file selected and read content AFTER file is selected

Comment: @ДамирКутиков - Certainly that's he usual way of doing it. However, there is no reason the idea can't work in response to a button-press. The press of course signifying the fact that a file has been chosen.. I'm disagreeing with your words "No. You *need* use" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Your answer fits more as a comment. You can either expand your answer by including sample code, or just comment on the question.